# SilverStripe - PhoneNumberField output

Tags: silverstripe, phone-number

I am trying to use `PhoneNumberField` to get the phone number but it gives the output as  an array. How can I get the exact input?

```
$mobilePhone = PhoneNumberField::create('MobileTelephone', 'Mobile Telephone  *');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are submitting your form to an action such as `public function send($data, $form) {...}` then you would retrieve the phone number with `PhoneNumberField::joinPhoneNumber($data['MobileTelephone'])`.

According to the [`PhoneNumberField` API description](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-PhoneNumberField.html):

> Field for displaying phone numbers. It separates the number, the area code and optionally the country code and extension.

Reading the [`PhoneNumberField` code](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-PhoneNumberField.html#30) we can see the field is a grouping of fields for the phone number's Country, Area, Number  and Extension. By default only the Number field is used, but it will still return the results as an array.

Comment: If i want to save phone number and country code how can i do it?  PhoneNumberField has a function to save data but it doesn't save with the country code

Comment: This is how to retrieve the full phone number: `PhoneNumberField::joinPhoneNumber($data['MobileTelephone'])`

Comment: when u add country code field , area & etc it gives in seperate lines. is there a way to get all them in one line??

Comment: This would be controlled with your css. If you inspect the elements with your browser tools you should be able to target those sepecfic fields and style the accordingly.